Sassoon stylistic set not working on Chrome
I am trying to use the stylistic set 9 of Sassoon font. It is working well on Firefox but on chrome it uses the default. Below is the css code
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SassoonInfantRegularWebFont';
    src: url('static/fonts/SassoonKit/webFonts/SassoonInfantRegular/font.woff2') format('woff2'), /* WOFF2 format */
         url('static/fonts/SassoonKit/webFonts/SassoonInfantRegular/font.woff') format('woff'); /* WOFF format */
    font-feature-settings: "ss09", "liga" off;
}

I have cleared cache and restarted chrome but it doesn't still work. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

What debugging have you tried? For example, different font, different feature settings (or none) and is your browser devtools showing the font loaded OK?

Move your font-feature-settings  to the actual style rules (they don't belong to the @font-face rule which only "registers" the font but doesn't apply any styles). Provided the font supports this style set it should work. To detect all available stylesheets you may also use this tool: https://wakamaifondue.com/
